# Using like and = in same mysqli prepared statement

Tags: select, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-like

I am having issues in getting the desired results in mysqli prepared statement. I am using both like and = in the where condition.

**// my search variables**

```
$a = "%{$_REQUEST['a']}%";
$b = "%{$_REQUEST['b']}%";
$search_from_date = $_REQUEST['from_date'];
$search_to_date = $_REQUEST['to_date'];
```

**// my query**

```
$q = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT t1.* from table1 t1 where (t1.a like ? and t1.b like ?) and (date(last_updated) between ? and ?) limit ".$start.','.$per_page);

$q->bind_param('ssss',$a,$b,$search_from_date,$search_to_date);
```

I am just not able to get the results if dates are considered while search. If I remove dates from the statement search on other fields works great works great.

**Tell me how can I remove the search condition itself from the statement if no input is there for that search condition. I mean if to_date is not specified query should substitute that column by 1**

By doing this I would get default 30 rows even if no search condition is specified.

Comment: You should use placeholders for start and per page variables as well

Comment: thanks for that will update it. Tell me how can I remove the search condition itself from the statement if no input is there for that search condition. I mean if to_date is not specified query should substitute that column by 1

Comment: You can have a string for your query, and use an IF statement in your PHP (or equivalent) to optionally add in an AND term to your WHERE clause.  Then once your string is complete, you can use that.

Comment: @Chrisky it is not that simple. with unknown number of placeholders you are bount to use call user func stuff

Comment: If you use the Bind functionality and have placeholders, then you will indeed have to get clever with how you fill in those placeholders.  However, if you concatenate well-formed terms to construct SQL, you can do this sort of thing successfully.   

An alternative approach: have some "SkipDateTerm" boolean parameter, then in the SQL you have: `AND (? = 1 OR timestamp between ? and ?)`  and then bind to `SkipDateTerm`, `FromDate` and `ToDate`.

Comment: thanks @Chrisky i did the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance the date formats are incompatable.  Many databases speak native ISO 8601 dates (yyyy-mm-dd).  Can you ensure your request dates are formatted correctly?

Comment: Can you run some test code, like

    select date(?), date(?)  and bind that to your input dates, to demonstrate how they get interpreted?